# Go through result query without foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I am currently working on a project where it would come in handy to deal with a query result without having to use foreach loops to access everything of the array.

Let me explain it with an example:

I am selecting something from the database like

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE clientgroupid = 1"
```

The shown result is

```
name    country    phone    clientgroupid

john america 12313 1

mike netherland 3123123 1
```

So I basically get 2 rows with that content as a result.

Now I would go on and run through that result array with a foreach and output it that way.

But that would limit my output to just 2 rows.
Which in the picture would result in the output of just enough input fields for 2 persons.

[image]

What I need is, that I show all results from the database in those input fields. 
But there not "filled out" fields should be shown as well - in order to give the Moderator the posibility to fill it out to add more people to the database.

Please correct me if my way of thinking is completly off here - I welcome all suggestions or solutions

Thank you

**EDIT**

The issue is as following:
When I get 2 rows as a result from the database I would only create 2 lines of content like here :

[image]

But I also want to have all other input fields shown, so that the moderator can add more clients if needed.

So the output with 2 found Clients and rest empty fields would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you put your code here? Would help me :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand what you mean by "What I need is, that I show *all* results from the database". Do you mean that you wish to show all results from all clientgroups?